# LyX question about nomenclature and editing custom styles

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

[image]

Three related questions:

1. What are these things called (that the arrows are pointed at)? (I'm going to refer to them as ***"custom styles"***.)
2. How does one edit these "custom styles"?
3. How does one copy these into new "custom styles" (with new names) so that one can edit the copies while leaving the originals unchanged (and so that these edited copies also start showing up in this list)?

---

Update: to add some more background to the question:

This is using the **LyXBook** layout (below). There doesn't seem to be a separate `.layout` file. I got the `.lyx` file from: https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Layouts (the filename is `LyXBook.lyx` and is contained in the `LyXBookSampler.zip` file downloadable under "2.Books" on that page).

[image]